# OpenID login on GIS.stackexchange.com does not work from Safari 5.0.3

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login, safari

Can't log in to GIS - login process appears to complete successfully (I use Yahoo! as my provider), but after redirecting back to GIS I'm still shown the "log in" link in the header.

I've tried doing a hard refresh, but no luck. I'm not blocking cookies or JavaScript from Stack Exchange.

*Can* log in to Meta. Using Safari 5.0.3.

I *can* log into GIS using Firefox.

Comment: Using which OpenID provider?  What happens exactly?  Did you try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: FWIW: I've confirmed that Michal *is* able to log in, but can't seem to *stay* logged in long enough to actually access the site. Hoping someone with Safari can shed some light on this...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce the issue at this time. If it remains an issue please let me know.